# empty Space on the right on my Website when using small Devices

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i really hope someone can help me, since this Issue gives me headache already.

I got this Site [www.Skilldate.de](https://www.skilldate.de/Pharmor/Pages/LandingPage.aspx) http://www.Skilldate.de an on the “Landing Page” if you decrease the Size of the Window (or directly open the Page via Mobile) you should already see the Problem :

There is always some unused Space on the right Side which makes the browser scroll on the width and i just dont know how to get rid of it, since it destroys the responsive feel

Iam grateful for every Inspiration
Cheers and regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You should have overflow-x hidden.

add in your css

```
#form1 {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```